# How does a child control get notified when its parent changes a visual property in the designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` that hosts a `DataGridView` component with a header and one data row.

I'm having an issue trying to notify the DataGridView when its container changes certain visual properties in the designer.

I override the BackColor property of the base UserControl to set the BackColor of the data row in the grid. The goal is that when I set the BackColor of the UserControl’s container it will trickle down to the Grid.

If I explicitly set the UserControl’s BackColor property, the design and runtime DataGridControl follows correctly.

If I just change the BackColor in the container what I have works at runtime, but is intermittent at design time.

Dropping the control on the container the data row BackColor follows the container color.

Changing the container’s BackColor doesn’t call the UserControl’s property setter to change the data row in the designer.

Changing the container does change other custom components I have created using `label` on a `TableLayoutPanel`. I don't set all labels to match the container so it must be using the property setter to get it right. They if I put a `MessageBox.Show("Setter Called");` in the property setter it doesn't always happen. in either the working or my target non-working control.

When I run the project the executable does change the row to match. As a bonus the designer color changes right after the executable is displayed and it remains the matching color even after I end the program.

I also tried the ParentChanged event on the UserControl but it only gets called when the program runs or I add or delete the control from the form. Just like the other properties. Never from changing the container in the IDE.

Using the Load event made the code work at RunTime.

Current code:

```
public JobPanel()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      dataGridView1.RowCount = 1;
      dataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
   }

[BrowsableAttribute(true)]
public override Color BackColor { get { return base.BackColor; } set { SetBackColor(value); } }

private void SetBackColor(Color value)
{
  if (BackColor != value) { //Makes no difference if we remove this test
    base.BackColor = value;
    if (dataGridView1 != null) {
      dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = BackColor;
      dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = BackColor;
    }
  }
}

private void JobPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = base.BackColor;
  dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = base.ForeColor;
}
```